# ADL: First row is header in format of file preview is not working

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-data-explorer

I have copied data from Oracle to data lake gen 1. And also considered my first row as a header while copying data. I am able to see my column names in the data lake file preview but column names are like 0,1,2,3,... and my actual column names are in the first row.

Tried to click on Format-->clicked on the First row is header-->Clicked on OK

But there is no change. It still looks the same way as it is before. My column names are still in the first row of the table.

How to set the column names correctly?

**Screenshots:**

*File preview:*

[image]

*Sink data format details:*

[image]

Comment: Did you also set first row as header in Sink dataset?

Comment: @LeonYue Yes, I did that. In the pipeline I have to do that, right?

Comment: Can you see the schema in Source dataset?

Comment: @shaik, could you please show some details or screenshots for us?

Comment: @LeonYue I have added screenshots. Can you please check? My first row is columns and default column names are integers.

Comment: @JosephXu There is no schema option available in the source dataset. Where to check for schema?

Comment: It seams that the sink setting is correct. Then please check the source dataset schema, import again like Joseph Xu said.

Comment: You're right. I see Oracle soruce dataset without schema tab.

Comment: @JosephXu Is this issue is related to Oracle? Are you also getting integers as column names in the sink dataset?

Comment: Hi @shaik moeed, No, I'm using Azure SQL, it has schema tab in source dataset. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzpsn.png)

Comment: @shaikmoeed can you try use query option to get the table data? If the output still miss the header. I think it's a bug.

Comment: @LeonYue I was using the query option to import data. The query consists of joins and selecting only required columns. I have also tried with the table option as well, which gives the same results i.e., integers as columns.

Comment: @shaikmoeed per my experience, it most like a by design issue. Sorry we can't give more useful helps for you.  Some suggestions are that: 1. Ask Azure support(it takes money and time but can get the root cause). 2. When import the file from data lake, ship the first row.

Comment: @LeonYue Thanks. I will consider your suggestions :)

Comment: @shaikmoeed you're welcome. May I post it as aswwer?

Comment: @LeonYue I don't think so as the issue hasn't resolved. But you can post all your suggestions mentioned in the comments which will be helpful for future readers. (Will upvote :) )

Comment: @shaikmoeed we can wait for two days.  if no others can give more helps, I will post it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

per my experience, it most like a by design issue. Sorry we can't give more useful helps for you. Some suggestions are that:

1. [Ask Azure support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request#:%7E:text=To%20start%20a%20support%20request%20from%20anywhere%20in,select%20Help%20%2B%20support.%20Select%20New%20support%20request.)(it takes money and time but can get the root
   cause).
2. Ignore this issue, when import the file from data lake, ship the first row.

HTH.